# Puntos y comas en JS, ¿Recomendado a nivel de rendimiento?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015, ecmascript

Sé que no es requerido el uso de ; en JS, pero para el interprete de JS que es más eficiente, ¿que lo pongamos o no?

Comment: Se supone que si lo solicita el mismo lenguaje, deberías ponerlo, no aparece error, si mal no estoy, pero te lanza una advertencia.

Comment: También podrías tener problemas al [minificar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) el código.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Si omites el punto y coma, el intérprete de javascript hace lo mejor posible para inferir dónde termina un bloque y empieza el siguiente.

Hay casos de borde. El intérprete puede asumir que un salto de línea implica un punto y coma donde no corresponde. Por ejemplo si escribes

```js
function escribe5() {
  return
  5    
}
console.log(escribe5())
```

el intérprete lo toma como

```
function escribe5() {
 return;
 5;    
}
```

Y por lo tanto devuelve `undefined`.

---

Otro caso que no es culpa del intérprete

Piensa que declaras una expresión de función

```
var mayuscula=function(texto) {
  return texto.toUpperCase();
};

(console.log(mayuscula('hola')));
```

lógicamente eso devuelve `HOLA`.

Si omites el punto y coma:

```js
var mayuscula=function(texto) {
  return texto.toUpperCase()
}
(console.log(mayuscula('hola')))
```

El intérprete asume que estás ejecutando inmediatamente la función pasándole el parámetro `console.log(mayuscula('hola'))` a `mayuscula`. Y eso te va a tirar un error. Repito, esto no es un error del intérprete. Hay casos en donde realmente quieres ejecutar la función de inmediato.

---

Otro ejemplo. Declaras una cadena de texto, una variable numérica y luego ejecutas una expresión regular sobre la cadena de texto:

```
var texto,numero;
texto="cadena de texto";
numero=0;
/cadena/g.exec(texto);
```

Esto imprime (en la consola del browser)

```
["cadena", index: 0, input: "cadena de texto", groups: undefined]
```

Si lo haces sin punto y coma:

```js
var texto,numero
texto="cadena de texto"
numero=0
/cadena/g.exec(texto)
```

El intérprete asumirá que `numero` es `0 / (cadena/g.exec(texto))` es decir, usa el inicio de la expresión regular como operador de división, y arrojará:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cadena is not defined
```

Comment: Y, precisamente porque el intérprete/compilador va a tener que asumir dónde termina cada sentencia, si añades todos los `;` necesarios, ahorras tareas a la máquina y será más eficiente (pero de manera marginal)

Comment: @Marcos eso dije. No puedes declarar strings multilínea con un salto de línea. Sí puedes agregar una secuencia de escape para añadir un salto usando \n. Pero con template literals sí puedes, reemplazando las comillas por backticks

Comment: @Marcos ¿Tú dices que el error de sintaxis se gatilla antes de que el intérprete trate de inferir dónde iría un punto y coma? Puede que tengas razón, mejor quitar esa parte de la respuesta

Comment: @amenadiel, no estoy seguro de si el intérprete va a tratar de arreglarlo agregando el `;`. Lo que quise decir es que agregando o no el `;` va a dar error, es decir, directamente no compila. En cambio en los otros ejemplos si va a compilar solo que el resultado será distinto del esperado.

Comment: @Marcos sí te entiendo, pero el linter en sublimetext lo marca como error `unterminated string constant`, por lo que me inclino a pensar que el error se gatilla antes que el intérprete haga lo suyo

Answer (score 13):

Respuesta Corta:
Si.

Repuesta Larga

Para saber si tenemos un buen Rendimiento con esto, debemos validar que dice la documentación de [**EcmaScript**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion) acerca de los punto y coma

> Las sentencias y declaraciones de ECMAScript deben finalizar con un
> punto y coma. Tales puntos y comas siempre pueden aparecer
> explícitamente en el texto de origen. Por conveniencia, sin embargo,
> tales puntos y comas pueden omitirse del texto fuente en ciertas
> situaciones. Estas situaciones se describen diciendo que los puntos y
> comas se insertan automáticamente en la secuencia de token del código
> fuente en esas situaciones.

*De igual forma si no quieres usar punto y coma por algunas razones debes respetar las reglas que las encontraras en el manual enlace como **11.9.1Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion***(Reglas para inserción de punto y coma automatico) y si quieres ver los ejemplos ***11.9.2Examples of Automatic Semicolon Insertion*** *(Ejemplos de punto y coma automaticos)*

El `;` significa el final de una instrucción y/o Sentencia , pero si queremos hacer un archivo **`.js`** que pesa menos (**`min.js`**) puede que los **`;`** que no añadiste te den problemas

```js
let a="SoEs";console.log(a);
```

```js
  let a="SoEs" console.log(a)
```

Como podemos ver en algunos de los casos es necesario el punto y coma y, esto hace difícil al interprete de javascript asumir las cosas, el solo hecho que dejar al interprete deducir cuando usar punto y coma y cuando no , pierde tiempo el interprete.

No Obstante,

En Algunos Frameworks nos dicen que es de ***"Buenas Practicas"*** no usarlo, pero,  **¿ Porque ?**

para evitar ***"errores tontos"*** que eviten que los frameworks puedan compilar rápidamente evitandonos el mal rato de la punto y coma.

**Y que hace el framework cuando quiero publicar una aplicacion JavaScript?**

Existe un programa que se encarga de transpilar el codigo, colocandole ";" y lleverlo a .**`min.js`** ademas de otras cosas , el  mas popular y usado es [**Babel**](https://babeljs.io/)