# ¿Por qué mi variable es undefined?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código para hacer un "slideshow" pero mi consola dice  "x[myIndex - 1] is undefined".

```js
var myIndex = 0;
animacion();

function animacion() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(animacion, 2000);    
}
```

¿Pueden ver el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para un array en Javascript la posición `-1` no existe, a menos que la definas explicita-mente, también se debe tener en cuenta que si los elementos del DOM no han sido cargados.

```js
var el_array = []
console.log(el_array[-1])
// salida undefined

var el_array = []
el_array[-1] = "algo"
console.log(el_array[-1])
// imprime algo
```

Para tu caso la variable `myIndex` debería iniciar en `1` asi cuando implementes la primera vez `x[myIndex-1]` sera equivalente a `x[0]`.

Ademas la sentencia `document.getElementsByClassName("slides");` retornara `undefined` dado que el script se ejecuta antes que se pinten los elementos, para solventar esto puedes:

1. Agrega el script al final del documento antes del cierre `</body>`
2. Usar el evento `DOMContentLoaded` que se ejecuta cuando el HTML del DOM ha sido creado.

Ahora un ejemplo de como quedaría el código completo:

```js
var myIndex = 1;

function animacion() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(animacion, 2000);    
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   // Llama la funcion animacion, cuado esta cargado el DOM
   animacion();
});
```

```html
<li class="slides"> HOLA 1</li>
<li class="slides"> HOLA 2</li>
<li class="slides"> HOLA 3</li>
<li class="slides"> HOLA 4</li>
<li class="slides"> HOLA 5</li>
```

Comment: Hmm entiendo, pero aun así me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, es como si despues del for ya no me reconociera la variable x porque en consola me dice que x no está definida, pero si lo esta!

Comment: asegurate de que tu script este al final del documento, porque es la forma en que x podria no tener los elementos `slides`

Comment: vaya, tenia mi script en un documento externo, pero lo puse dentro de mi html justo despues de todos los elementos y funcionó perfecto, no entiendo por qué

Comment: @ErnestoGutierrez  he actualizado el código con el evento `DOMContentLoaded` que se ejecuta cuando el HTML del DOM ha sido creado.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que te falta un punto y coma en la asignación del `if`.

```
var myIndex = 1;
animacion();

function animacion() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1;}    
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(animacion, 2000);    
}
```

Comment: En JS el punto y coma es opcional salvo algunos escenarios que no creo sea este

Comment: Ya, lo digo porque, al ser una asignación... Creo que es uno de los casos sensibles. Vamos, según recuerdo.

Comment: Revisa aquí más al respecto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146487/puntos-y-comas-en-js-recomendado-a-nivel-de-rendimiento

Comment: Tienes razón. Lo he probado y, efectivamente, no afecta. Disculpas y gracias por  la aclaración.